# Excel: Lookup the value that is within a certain time range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

imagine that I have two spreadsheets, one with tenants that lived in my properties and one with the repairs that were done in the properties after the tenant left. Here is how they look. 
Tenancies:

```
 Property ID | Tenant ID | Start of Tenancy | End of Tenancy | Start of next tenancy
 1           | 1         | 01/01/2001       | 30/01/2001     | 15/02/2001
 1           | 2         | 15/02/2001       | 28/02/2001     | 15/03/2001
 1           | 3         | 15/03/2001       | 30/03/2001     | 15/04/2001
 2           | 4         | 15/01/2001       | 30/01/2001     | 31/01/2001
 2           | 4         | 31/01/2001       | 30/04/2001     | 05/05/2001
 2           | 5         | 05/05/2001       | 05/06/2001     | 20/06/2001
 3           | 6         | 03/05/2001       | 15/08/2001     | 30/08/2001
 3           | 7         | 30/08/2001       | 15/10/2001     | 15/11/2001
 4           | 1         | 31/01/2001       | 30/04/2001     | 15/05/2001
 4           | 8         | 15/05/2001       | 30/08/2001     | 30/09/2001
```

Repairs:

```
 Property ID | Repair Issued Date |
 1           | 08/03/2001         |
 1           | 10/04/2001         |
 2           | 03/05/2001         |
 2           | 15/06/2001         |
 3           | 18/08/2001         |
 4           | 10/05/2001         |
 4           | 15/09/2001         |
```

I need to find out who was the tenant before the repair was done.  Thus, I need to match a 'Property ID' and ,if 'Repair Issued Date' falls in a range between the 'End of Tenancy' And 'Start of next tenancy', assign the 'Tenant ID'. Simple example, the first repair in a property '1' was on 08/03/2001 which falls between the range of void for Tenant '2', so assign the tenant ID to next column.

Normally, if there would be only one tenant per property, I could do a simple lookup, but this complicates my situation.

I tried to play around with vlookup and dates functions, but could not figure out the way to do it.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the SUMIFS function. Adding up all Tenant ID that match, provided there is only ever one, will result in the Tenant ID:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,G2,D:D,"<" & H4,E:E,">" & H2)
```

As suggested by @Tom Sharpe, you could test for multiple matches and 'error' those out:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,G2,C:C,"<" & H2,E:E,">" & H2)>1,"#MULTIPLE FOUND",SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,G2,C:C,"<" & H2,E:E,">" & H2))
```

Comment: I don't think that's a bad idea. Maybe you could use a COUNTIFS to check that there is only one?

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe, I've altered the answer to utilise this idea.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for an INDEX with multiple criteria for the matching row number. The row number can be returned with AGGREGATE by forcing everything that doesn't match into an error state while discarding errors.

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$11)/((A$1:A$11=G2)*(D$1:D$11<=H2)*(E$1:E$11>=H2)), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and the formula works exactly as I need. There are two issues though. First, since I have quite large datasets (126000 rows and 20000 rows) it is impossible to scale this up. Second, in some cases I get #NUM! error, even though the reference is correct.

Comment: If I was working on 126K rows,I would move to VBA and work completely in a 2-D variant array the return the values to the worksheet *en masse*. There is nothing that is not going to cause an appreciable amount of calculation lag using native worksheet formulas. The `#REF!` error comes from no match found and can be avoided with an IFERROR wrapper. I cannot comment further on the #REF! error since I have no data that reproduces the issue.